# Restrict messages in firestore to a list of userids

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have taken over a project which has the following data model in firestore:

/Chat/{chatId}/messages/{messageId}

```
/Chat/{chatId}
{
  users: ["24","51"]
  messages: [ //collection
    {message:"...", sender: 24, time:"...", users: ["24","51"]},
  ]
}
```

Through flutter I'm reading the chat via:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
             .collection("Chat")
             .doc(chatID.toString())
             .collection("messages")
             .orderBy("time", descending: false)
             .snapshots(),
```

I need to ensure that only the two users that is involved in the chat is allowed to read the messages, but have a hard time doing so.

My current rules look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {  
    match /Chat/{chatId}{
      allow read: if "24" in resource.data.users //24 is being replaced with request.auth.uid when it works
      allow write
      
      match /messages/{messageId}{
        allow read: if "24" in resource.data.users //24 is being replaced with request.auth.uid when it works
        allow write
        }
    }
  }
}
```

With the above, I'm getting a permission error when trying to list the chats through flutter, it gives the error:

```
Chat/1103/messages failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

How do I write a rule where it's only the the two users that is able to read and write to the messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security [rules do not filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters). Instead they merely ensure that your code does not try to read more data than it's authorized for.

Since your rules say that the code can only read messages that the user is a collaborator on, your code should also limit its reading to such messages. So: add a condition to your query:

```
where('users', whereArrayContains: 'uidOfCurrentUser')
```

With that additional condition the rules can see that you're not trying to read more data than allowed.